# How can I create a new data frame based on different classes from an original data frame?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a data frame that has 96 classes, I want to create a new one based on 20 classes from the original, these should contain the same amount of  rows they have at the original data.

I was trying to use: `df2 = df[df.class == ["class_a","class_b",...,"class_20"]]`

But I'm getting an error.

Comment: hi, did you try `df[df.class.isin(["class_a", "class_b", ..., "class_20"])]`?

Comment: I just found it after 2 hours searching. Thank you!

Comment: Here, you don't mean *"its Python class is actually 96 classes"*, you only mean *"96 string columns whose names are names of classes"*.